# Write test for Schedule run three batches inside it!

Tags: unit-test, batch, schedule

I'm a newbie in salesforce. So now I want to write test for schedule that have three batches inside it like below. So how can I write test for it? Thank you so much!

```
public with sharing class ScheduleService implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Id batchId1 = Database.executeBatch(
            new BatchDayService(id1),
            1000
        );

        Id batchId2 = Database.executeBatch(
            new BatchDayService(id2),
            1000
        );

        Id batchId3 = Database.executeBatch(
            new BatchDayService(id3),
            1000
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. we're not a code writing service; you'll need to demonstrate some effort.  There are many examples on this site as well as in the doc on how to test schedulables

Comment: Generally speaking, tests don't really work with multiple layers of async code. You can call your `execute()` methods in a test like you would any other method, e.g. `ScheduleService.execute(null)` (the context variable is generally useless to us). Testing the execution of `Database.executeBatch(new BatchDayService())` though is probably going to be tricky.

Comment: @cropredy This is one of those times I disagree with that take. It's easy to find out how to test a Schedulable, or a Batchable, but testing logic that schedules multiple Batchables and gets 100% coverage requires something I wouldn't expect a newer developer (or even some more experienced ones) to necessarily know.

Answer (score 0):

To get the test to pass, but also get coverage, you need to use `Database.rollback` to prevent the actual execution of the code. This means you can't test the class in the usual manner (by scheduling a job). Instead, call the code directly:

```
Test.startTest();
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
new ScheduleService().execute((SchedulableContext)null);
Database.rollback(sp);
Test.stopTest();
```

This will get 100% coverage and won't fail, but you'll still want to independently unit test each batchable class.

Comment: thank for your answer. I tried it, but it's just covered for first batch in schedule class. And other lines contain two batches like below, they're not covered
```
Id batchId2 = Database.executeBatch(
            new BatchDayService(id2),
            1000
        );

Id batchId3 = Database.executeBatch(
            new BatchDayService(id3),
            1000
        );
```
Please help me to schedule can cover all three batches in schedule class, thank you so much! @sfdcfox

Comment: @Richard If they're not covered, maybe there's some kind of exception or other error? It's not possible for just one to work without the others in the simplified code you have. I've replicated something like it in my org to confirm it still works--it does. It may be that something you've omitted is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Could one not also assert the presence of 3 AsyncApexJob records to verify 3 batchables were launched?

Comment: I am assuming the "it doesn't work" is because the batch execution requests are being rolled back before the stopTest call which would run the batches. The problem is the use of the save point and rollback. Remove both and this test should work. The stopTest can execute the three queued batches and the test can then assert against the results in the DB.

Comment: (Importantly, the batches do not chain but rather are all three queued up in the same transaction.)

Comment: I do, however, agree that the test of the scheduled job should just verify the queuing of the batches and that the batch class should be separately unit tested).